# Change K2 User Group with php

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

How can I assign a different usergroup to the active user with php?

I believe I can get the active user by using the following code:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$user_id = $user->get('id');
```

but how can I change the usergroup?

Thanks!

Comment: You're question might be best asked on the K2 forum :)

Comment: Thanks Lodder, I've done that but there's been no replies so far so I thought I'd ask here too!

Answer (score 0):

You change the user group by following coding

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$group_id = '6'; //Group ID
$user->set('gid', $group_id);
```

Comment: Thank you. Will that work for the K2 user or is that just the joomla user?

Comment: Do you know how I could do that for K2?